# js array sort not working properly

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm sorting an array of objects, but something in my evaluation is not working properly. Any insight would be really helpful, I'm starting to work in circles.

```
temp = [{name: 'M12-20'}, {name: 'M20-25'}];

a[field] = "M12-20"
b[field] = "M20-25"

temp.sort(function(a, b) {
    var one = /[MFP]\d{2}/.exec(a[field]) || /[MFP]\d{1}/.exec(a[field]);
    var two = /[MFP]\d{2}/.exec(b[field]) || /[MFP]\d{1}/.exec(b[field]);

    return ( one[0] > two[0]  ? 1 : -1);
  });
```

Comment: The `.exec()` method returns an **array** if there's a match. (Also it's not clear how you want those things ordered; is it just by the numeric value?)

Comment: right, i've been doing return( one[0] > two[0] ? 1 : -1; to no luck

Comment: How are we supposed to answer this if we have no idea what's in `temp`? Please show us a reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JLRishe yes I hadn't fully grasped that part ...

Comment: @JLRishe Its a really simple array of objects, code has been updated to reflect a small sample

Comment: @atlMapper And can we assume that the value of `field` is `"name"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only assume that what you're trying to do is extract the first number from each of those values and compare them, but if so, you're doing it incorrectly. `a[0]` and `b[0]` will produce the entire matched value if there is a match.

Your use of Regex is also more complicated than it needs to be.

Try this:

```
var temp = [{name: 'M12-20'}, {name: 'M20-25'}],
    field = 'name',
    r = /[MFP](\d\d?)/;

temp.sort(function(a, b) {
    var one = r.exec(a[field]) || [,NaN],
        two = r.exec(b[field]) || [,NaN];

    return one[1] - two[1];
});
```

FYI (a side note) - Using `return condition ? -1 : -1;` in a sort comparison function is almost always wrong. The function needs to return `0` if the two values are equivalent in order. Neglecting to do this can result in incorrect results, inefficient behavior, or if you're really unlucky, an infinite loop.

Comment: Your absolutely right, I'm trying to compare the numbers up until the dash for each value. That dash in the string was throwing off the comparison.

Comment: @atlMapper It was actually the `M` in the string that was throwing off the comparison.

Comment: Ahh...I see what your saying and how your solution is working(I think). Greedy regex looking for both numbers, either an array of results is built or an empty array is given for comparison. Thanks

Comment: FYI The side note is wrong: Please read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @Skywalker Which part am I supposed to be looking at?

Comment: You are saying:Using return condition ? -1 : -1; in a sort comparison function is almost always wrong.  That is not correct.

Comment: @Skywalker I know what I said. And which part of that page contradicts what I said?

Comment: I made a copy of the lines at the bottom of my answer below.

Comment: @Skywalker And how do those lines contradict what I said? Do they use `return condition ? -1 : 1;`? They don't look like they do. No, those lines pretty much confirm exactly what I said.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
var temp=[];
temp[1]="Apple";
temp[2]="Orange";
temp[3]="Banana";

temp.sort(function(a, b) {
  return return (a < b) ? 1 : -1;  
});
```

From the source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```
if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion) {
  return -1;
}
if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion) {
  return 1;
}
// a must be equal to b
return 0;
```

Comment: Contrary to the snippet you quoted from MDN, your function returns `1` if `a` and `b` are equal. I also don't see how this answer has anything to do with the specific question asked above.

Comment: That does not change the fact that you have an incorrect statement in your answer. The second half of my answer exlains the possible return values. As you may agree, the retun values waas the essence of th question. You failed to answer that correct.

Comment: You still have yet to explain what was incorrect about my answer. It is _not_ incorrect, for the very same reason that your answer _is_ incorrect. I think you need to work on your reading skills because you have both misunderstood the point I was making, and misunderstood the point of OP's question. The asker did not need to have the basics of sorting explained to him/her. S/he already understood that much just fine.